# Execute a selector within another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I would like to create a UITableViewController within another controller, as well as pass it a method from that controller. I already read that this can be achieved by using @selector. Now I tried the following:

TimeController.m

```
- (void)choseTime{
    SelectOptionController *selectController = [[SelectOptionController alloc] initWithArray:[Time SQPFetchAll] andSelector:@selector(timeSelected)];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectController animated:true];
}

- (void) timeSelected{
    NSLog(@"Time selected!");
}
```

SelectOptionController.h

```
@interface SelectOptionController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataset;
@property (nonatomic) SEL selectedMethod;

-(id)initWithArray: (NSMutableArray *) myArray andSelector: (SEL) selectedMethod;
```

SelectOptionController.m

```
- (id)initWithArray: (NSMutableArray *) myArray andSelector: (SEL) selectedMethod{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if(self) {
        self.dataset = myArray;
        self.selectedMethod = selectedMethod;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSelector:self.selectedMethod];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
}
```

However, when a cell gets selected, the following exception is being thrown:

```
-[SelectOptionController timeSelected]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1450f140
```

What am I doing wrong over here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `timeSelected` on `self` which is actually SelectOptionController, but the timeSelected method exists in the TimeController class.

Assuming you don't want to move `timeSelected` to SelectOptionController, you need to pass a reference to the TimeController to the new SelectOptionController and call the selector on that. A selector is simply a reference to a method, not the method itself. You will probably want to store it as a weak reference too too.

E.g.

```
@interface SelectOptionController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataset;
@property (nonatomic) SEL selectedMethod;
@property (nonatomic, weak) TimeController *timeController;
```

And

```
- (id)initWithArray: (NSMutableArray *) myArray andSelector: (SEL) selectedMethod timeController:(TimeController*)timeController {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if(self) {
        self.dataset = myArray;
        self.selectedMethod = selectedMethod;
        self.timeController = timeController;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.timeController performSelector:self.selectedMethod];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
}
```

With all of that said, the above will get your code working but this isn't a particularly good pattern. I would suggest you look into [Prototypes and Delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) for implementing this behaviour, or if you want to pass the method itself, do some research on [Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html). But hopefully this helps you better understand how selectors work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is working now. What I want to do is push a TableViewController and use it as a Pickerview, so that the user can select a row. When a row is selected, I want this data to be passed to the parent view, so that I can use it there. Is there a better way to do it then pass a selector?

Comment: I would implement a protocol for your SelectOptionController and a weak delegate property. A protocol basically defines method/s (and/or properties) that your delegate is expected to have. When you init the SelectOptionController, set the delegate to `self` (i.e. the TimeController) and ensure TimeController conforms to your newly created protocol. You can then call the method you defined in your protocol on your delegate (from SelectOptionController). If you haven't worked with protocols before, I would suggest doing a bit of research on how they work.